# Implementing operations for Number classes

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm currently working on a library that provides a mathematical interface for different operations. Operations like solving an equation or calculate derivatives of a function. With a recent update in the requirements, I have to include Scalar and Complex numbers, as well as Vectors and Matrices. With this second part, I came up with a rough, not so elegant - to say the least - solution. To be honest, I don't see how I could simplify things. 
Here's my current approach:
Extending the Number class, I added Scalar and Complex types:

```
public final class Scalar extends Number {

    private String real;

    public Scalar(String real) {
        this.real = real;
    }
    public Scalar(Double real) { this.real = real.toString(); }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return Double.valueOf(real).intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return Double.valueOf(real).longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return Double.valueOf(real).floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return Double.valueOf(real);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return real.toString();
    }
}

public class Complex extends Number {
    private Scalar real,
                   imaginary;

    public Complex(String real) {
        this.real = new Scalar(real);
        this.imaginary = new Scalar("0");
    }
    public Complex(Double real) {
        this.real = new Scalar(real);
        this.imaginary = new Scalar("0");
    }
    public Complex(String real, String imaginary) {
        this.real = new Scalar(real);
        this.imaginary = new Scalar(imaginary);
    }
    public Complex(Double real, Double imaginary) {
        this.real = new Scalar(real);
        this.imaginary = new Scalar(imaginary);
    }

    public Double imaginary() {
        return imaginary.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return real.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return real.longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return real.floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return real.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s%c%si",
                real.toString(),
                imaginary.intValue() < 0 ? '-' : '+',
                imaginary.intValue() < 0 ? -1.0 * imaginary.doubleValue() :
                        imaginary.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Don't mind with the toString implementations, they're only there for debugging purposes and will be removed later. For simplicity's sake I haven't included Vector/Matrix types at this stage.
Now, I need a way to define operators for these classes.

```
public class Calculator {

    public static
    <T extends Number,
     U extends Number>
    Number add(final T lhs,
                   final U rhs)
        throws ArithmeticException
    {
        Class<? extends Number> lClass = lhs.getClass(),
                                rClass = rhs.getClass();

        if (Scalar.class.equals(lClass) && Scalar.class.equals(rClass)) {
            return addScalar((Scalar) lhs, (Scalar) rhs);
        }

        if (Complex.class.equals(lClass) && Complex.class.equals(rClass)) {
            return addComplex((Complex) lhs, (Complex) rhs);
        }

        if (Complex.class.equals(lClass) && !Complex.class.equals(rClass)) {
            return addScalarToComplex((Scalar) rhs, (Complex) lhs);
        }

        if (Complex.class.equals(rClass) && !Complex.class.equals(lClass)) {
            return addScalarToComplex((Scalar) lhs, (Complex) rhs);
        }

        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }

    private static Scalar addScalar(final Scalar lop, final Scalar rop) {
        return new Scalar(lop.doubleValue() + rop.doubleValue());
    }

    private static Complex addComplex(final Complex lop, final Complex rop) {
        return new Complex(lop.doubleValue() + rop.doubleValue(),
                lop.imaginary() + rop.imaginary());
    }

    private static Complex addScalarToComplex(final Scalar lop, final Complex rop) {
        return new Complex(lop.doubleValue() + rop.doubleValue(), rop.imaginary());
    }
}
```

Now this, is my main concern. It feels horrible to implement the operations like above, but I can't really come up with anything else. This works, it does the job but at the cost of a code quality. What could I improve here?
I thought of defining operations in Scalar/Complex types but it also feels rather "dirty". What about Scalar+Complex, where should that be implemented? I feel like, having the exact same code in Scalar and Complex classes is the bigger evil. This becomes an issue when implementing multiplication for Vectors not to mention Matrices. The same code in all 4 classes, but If I put it into the base class, I'm back to my current solution...

Comment: Why do you treat scalars as different objects than numbers? Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: True, but I can't define operators for the Numbers class without casting it to a concrete implementation.

Comment: I think you could treat them as Double. Have you ever heard about [composite pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite)? If not, I could make you an example.

Comment: I know composite pattern but I have no idea how it would eliminate code duplication: Scalar+Complex<>Comper+Scalar. So with the Operations I think I'd still be stuck with my current approach, which is yet again seems horrible but at least it's horrible in only a single file :D.

Comment: I believe that if you extend the Number class you'll always found stuck, that's because it hasn't methods for the imaginary part. In my opinion you should make a single class for Scalars and Complex, integers and real numbers simply have imaginary unit equal to 0.

Comment: That's actually a great idea. I'd have to implement the math operators to Complex numbers anyway.

Comment: But then (depending on th scope of this project), OP might need to discard Complex numbers to instore Quaternions instead. Conversely, when using Complex instead of Real, you lose operations (the comparison). So a subclass of Real numbers would bring this functionality back. A Integer class would bring modulo, and polynoms, etc. It would be great to make it work as separate classes. But yeah, that Java Number class is limiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is fun! Here are a few remarks:

---

### Drop Java's Number class

As @Checkinator said, this class will be limiting to you, because it cannot `extend` a higher-level class.

You are going to have to work outside Java's number framework, but you may hook back in with a `<? extends Number> asNumber();` method (for printing etc.)

---

### Complex extends Number

This is backwards:

> ```
> public class Complex extends Number {
> ```

Yes, mathematically the complex number *extends* the real number to the 2D plane. However, this `extends` is Java class relationship, and it works the other way around. You need `Real extends Complex` because:

- `Real`s are a subset (a mathematical restriction!) of `Complex`
- `Real` *extends* the functionality of `Complex` (by adding a total ordering, etc.)

So if we were to use inheritance, we'd inherit the other way around.

---

### > What about Scalar+Complex

This problem is now solved: Scalar + Complex is a `Complex` operation (where the Scalar is *Enmedded* in the Complex plane - because it *is* a Complex). Don't sweat it, defer that to `Complex.add()`.

**This is the key issue in your code!**

---

### Inheritance is annoying

Inheritance forces you to reuse everything from the mother class. This imposes restrictions in how you design the mother class:

- If I put a `double realPart` and `double imaginaryPart` in `Complex`, all numbers will be able to access an imaginary part. I'll have to *ensure* everywhere that part is well-constrained.
- Worse, the real part will *have* to be stored as a `double`. Even for `Integer`, or `Rational` subclasses. I would have prefered using one `int` and  two `int`s, respectively!

What you really want to pass down from mother class to subclass, is functionalities, not necessarily implementations. Interfaces do that perfectly well, as they inherit each other without bringing an annoying implementation with them:

```
interface Complex {
    Real getRealPart();
    Real getImaginaryPart();
    Complex add(Complex other);
    Complex multiply(Complex other);
}

interface Real extends Complex, Comparable<Real>{
    Real add(Real other);
    Real multiply(Real other);
}

interface MyInteger extends Real{
    MyInteger add(MyInteger other);
    MyInteger multiply(MyInteger other);
    MyInteger modulo(MyInteger mod);
}
```

Note I added elementary "natural" operations on those objects, while you introduced an Operator Object. It's purely for quality of life and both can co-exist.

---

### But how do I reuse my code without inheritance, you may ask?

Right, when you use interfaces and do not subclass, you lose the implementations. But you don't have to do it all over again! Here comes @Checkinator's *other* proposal: the Composite Pattern.

So a Complex implementation could be *composed* of two `Real`s:

```
public class XYComplex implements Complex {
    Real realPart;
    Real imaginaryPart;
    // Implementations of the interface's methods
}
```

One nice thing is that you could switch between representations of a complex (I proposed real/img, but you could go R.e^i.Theta etc.) and use Strategy pattern to alternate between representations.

Though to be honest, I'd favor an immutable implementation, where the same Complex number had one or several immutable *representations* at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your `Operator` class, you could consider applying your Binary Operators in two passes with a **partial application** (think functional languages). This will prevent having to check all combinations of type of each operands.

With this scheme, you have more control over operator application:

```
public interface BinaryOperator<T, U, R> {
    PartialApplication<T, U, R> applyPartially(T t);
}

public interface UnaryOperator<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}

public interface PartialApplication<T, U, R> implements UnaryOperator<U, R> {
    public T getFirstArgument();
}
```

In addition, the intermediate PartialApplication might be Operator-specific **and** be first-member-specific.

Adding an Integer to something else:

```
public static class PartialIntegerAddition<U, R> implements PartialApplication<MyInteger, U, R>{

    private MyInteger t;
    public PartialIntegerAddition(MyInteger t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(U u) {
        if(MyInteger.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyInteger uInteger = (MyInteger) u;
            return (R) uInteger.add(t); // natural MyInteger addition
        }
        if(MyReal.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyReal uReal = (MyReal) u;
            return (R) uReal.add(t); // natural MyReal addition
        }
        if(MyComplex.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyComplex uComplex = (MyComplex) u;
            return (R) uComplex.add(t); // natural MyComplex addition
        }
        throw new ArithmeticException("Unable to perform the operation");
    }

    @Override
    public MyInteger getFirstArgument() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

Adding a Real to something else:

```
public static class PartialRealAddition<U, R> implements PartialApplication<MyReal, U, R>{

    private MyReal t;
    public PartialRealAddition(MyReal t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(U u) {
        if(MyReal.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyReal uReal = (MyReal) u;
            return (R) uReal.add(t); // natural MyReal addition
        }
        if(MyComplex.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyComplex uComplex = (MyComplex) u;
            return (R) uComplex.add(t); // natural MyComplex addition
        }
        throw new ArithmeticException("Unable to perform the operation");
    }

    @Override
    public MyReal getFirstArgument() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

Adding a Complex to something else:

```
public static class PartialComplexAddition<U, R> implements PartialApplication<MyComplex, U, R>{

    private MyComplex t;
    public PartialComplexAddition(MyComplex t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public R apply(U u) {
        if(MyComplex.class.isInstance(u)) {
            MyComplex uComplex = (MyComplex) u;
            return (R) uComplex.add(t); // natural MyComplex addition
        }
        throw new ArithmeticException("Unable to perform the operation");
    }

    @Override
    public MyComplex getFirstArgument() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Now these 3 implementations can be brought together using this generic Addition Operator (which works with Integers, Reals, complexes, and can be expanded for any super or sub-classes!):

```
public static class GeneralAddition {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T, U, R> R apply(T t, U u) {
        PartialApplication<T, U, R> partialApplication;
        if(MyInteger.class.isInstance(t)) {
            MyInteger tInteger = (MyInteger) t;
            partialApplication = (PartialApplication<T, U, R>) new PartialIntegerAddition<U, R>(tInteger);
        } else if(MyReal.class.isInstance(t)) {
            MyReal tReal = (MyReal) t;
            partialApplication = (PartialApplication<T, U, R>) new PartialRealAddition<U, R>(tReal);
        } else if(MyComplex.class.isInstance(t)) {
            MyComplex tComplex = (MyComplex) t;
            partialApplication =  (PartialApplication<T, U, R>) new PartialComplexAddition<U, R>(tComplex); 
        } else {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Unable to perform the operation");
        }
        return partialApplication.apply(u);
    }
}
```

---

### Example usage:

We've see that we can perform any operation on any combination of Number types, and always get the most specific subtype.

```
public static void main(String[] argc){
    MyInteger a = new MyIntegerImpl(5);
    MyReal b = new MyRealImpl(2.5);
    GeneralAddition addition = new GeneralAddition();
    MyReal result = addition.apply(a, b); // Note: return type is imposed by programmer. May fail (ClassCast) if incoherent. The real type will be the lowest common denominator of the input types.
}
```

**Note:** The return type is set by the Programmer. If it is wrong (too specific), it will fail with a ClassCastException. Java cannot infer the correct type automatically because it is illegal to impose a bound on a generic type, base on other generic types:

```
public <R super U & V, U, V> R add(T t, U u); // Java error
```

Its true type will still be `MyReal`, though, so it is mathematically correct.

Otherwise you can simplify it and lock that `R` return type to the highest-level Object (`Complex`?) like you did using `Number`.

---

### Wrap up

- We have many implementations of each Number types
- The GenericAddition selects the proper PartialOperator for left hand side (1 check)
- The PartialApplication implementations make the minimum number of checks (1 each)